# Array filling aynschronously? (React function unintended)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state, next.js

I have a React component structured like this:

```
class SearchElement extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            otherArray: [],
            testArray: [],
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    otherEvent = (event) => {
        this.setState( { otherArray:event.target.value }, this.handleClick);
    }
    
    handleClick() {
        const { otherArray } = this.state;
        var exampleArray = [];
        console.log("THIS SHOULD BE EMPTY");
        console.log(exampleArray);
        console.log("exampleArray already has elements in it");
        //...
        //changes made to exampleArray
        this.setState({ testArray: exampleArray });
    }
```

otherEvent is called by a click on a HTML button which then should call handleClick as a callback function in the setState call. However when the print statements are shown exampleArray somehow already has elements (and it's also not the correct elements). I'm using NextJS if that is relevant. I'm assuming I'm confusing something about the asynchronous calls or how React state is maintained. Please let me know if there is more information I should provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your whole code. Could you change your `var` to `let` and see if the problem persists?

Comment: can you post a codesandbox.io example which reproduces this issue ?